Ac unit line set sight glass
I'm looking at my outdoor unit. It started and the sight glass is shaking pretty good. It seems like it's cavitation because I can see air bubbles passing through. I didn't think there was supposed to be any air in with the freon.

I added sentence structure to increase English readability. However, you have not actually asked a question (though one could be inferred). Please edit your question to include pictures, model number of the AC unit, and an actual question of what you want to find out. As now, this topic may be closed as needing details.

How much time has elapsed between start up and the view in the sight glass?

the bubbles may be freon gas

Bubbles are not cavitation. Cavitation is a vacuum and collapses almost immediately, causing destructive shock waves. Bubbles are just bubbles.

no changes to edit in necessary info, downvoted.

Some bubbles at start up is not uncommon. However they should go away after a minute or so of the unit running.  It does indicate air, but a very minor amount.
If the bubbles are there the entire time the unit runs, there is excessive air in the system and a service should be ordered to check for leaks and freon loss.
